# Oracle Dropping Triggers, Tables, indexs, and Sequences Order

Tags: sql, oracle

I put together a script that drops triggers, tables, indexes, and sequences.

```
    BEGIN
/*Delete All Triggers */
FOR i in (select trigger_name,owner 
              from dba_triggers ) LOOP  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TRIGGER '||i.owner||'.'||i.trigger_name;  
  END LOOP;  
/*Delete All Indexes*/
FOR ind IN 
(SELECT index_name FROM user_indexes WHERE table_name = 'my_table' AND index_name NOT IN 
   (SELECT unique index_name FROM user_constraints WHERE 
      table_name = 'my_table' AND index_name IS NOT NULL))
LOOP
  execute immediate 'DROP INDEX '||ind.index_name;
END LOOP;
/*Delete All Tables*/
FOR c IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables) LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS');
END LOOP;
/*Delete all Sequences*/
FOR s IN (SELECT sequence_name FROM user_sequences) LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP SEQUENCE ' || s.sequence_name);
END LOOP;

END;
```

I was wondering if there is specific order I should do it? Is there anything else I need to consider?

Comment: There is no such restrictions, while dropping table it automatically drops `index` and `trigger`. Here dropping index and trigger is unnecessary.

Comment: I have a similar script to drop all user objects. I just run it multiple times until all are deleted.